# How to install IE11 on windows server 2012 standard

Tags: internet-explorer-11, windows-server-2012-r2

I have IE 10 installed on windows server 2012 standard. I want to download and install IE11, but I see no option to do that. We have few apps which we are making compatible to IE11 and being a developer I can't install it on my machine.

Any ideas/help on this you be great

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, IE11 is only available for Window 7 and Windows 8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only option they give you right now (11/21/2013) is to upgrade your operating system to Windows Server 2012 R2, which comes with IE 11 preinstalled.

Comment: This is another side effect of Win8.1 being an "update" but Server 2012 R2 being an upgrade.

Comment: As of April 2019, it seems to be possible. See 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-server-2012-and-windows-embedded-8-standard-april-16-2019-e9eca154-ddab-db65-d9b4-66646adadf8f

Answer (score 2):

Nothing promising officially - see supported operating systems here: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn268945.aspx
The only option given there not yet mentioned here, is to run on 2008R2 with SP1.